# put rendered input value inside another input field

Tags: javascript, input, field

i'm trying to put the rendered value of the 1st input field to the second input field 
but i'm having some problems with the output

here is the code:

```
<script>
   function displayNumber(){     
      var card = document.getElementById('credit').value;

      var str = "";
      for(var i=1; i <= card.length-4; i++) {
         str += "*";
      }

      ecard = str + card.substr(card.length-4);
      document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = ecard;
      $("#output").val(ecard);
   }

   window.onload = displayNumber; 
</script>

<form id="myform">
   <input type="text" id="credit"   value="123456789012">
   <br>
   <input type="text" id="output" > 
</form> 

<label id="out"></label>
```

The value of credit that is 123456789012

should appear inside the input field "output" as

```
********9012
```

here is the demo
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fdRTR/45/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code should work, assured that you are using jQuery library, which I doubt cause you are using both javascript vanilla syntax and jQuery one. So make sure you are including the jQuery library for that to work.

If you are not going to use jQuery, then replace your following line:

```
$("#output").val(ecard);
```

for this one:

```
document.getElementById('output').value = ecard;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to push the value to output, it should be:

```
document.getElementById('output').value = ecard;
```

I just updated your Fiddle and should work.

In the input tag, the value is not set by doing `<input>value</input>`. Instead, the value is set using the "value" property which is why innerHTML property won't work, but the value property will.

In your Fiddle, you are using No-Library (pure JS) which means that you can't use the jQuery syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use jQuery you must wait until it has loaded. Instead of using `window.onload` try `$(document).ready()` like so

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    displayNumber();

});
```

If you plan to use only `displayNumber` on your document, a shorthand way to do this would be like this

```
$(document).ready(displayNumber);
```